# Alternating row colors in UITableView

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

How do I get alternating row colors in a UITableView using monotouch?

I am currently populating my TableView using this:

```
public partial class myViewController : UITableViewController
    {
        public static UINavigationController navigationController;
        public static IntPtr handle;

        public CompanyViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }


        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            Services service = new Services();

            var myList = service.GetList(param1);

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach(var c in myList)
            {
                list.Add (c.Name);
            }

            navigationController = NavigationController;
            handle = Handle;
            var source = new CompanyTableSource(list);

            myTableView.Source = source;

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this class:

```
public class AlternatingTableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
{
    public override void WillDisplay (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row % 2 == 0) {
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        } else {
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in you tableview:

```
var tvdelegate = new AlternatingTableViewDelegate()
myTableView .Delegate = tvdelegate
```

Comment: In which event should the delegate be assigned?

Comment: In your viewdidload, where you also assign the datasource

Comment: The UITableView is used to drill down into the row that is touched. It seems that adding this causes the UITableView not to allow navigation to the next view. Adding base.Willappear is not allowed. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't say exactly without seeing the complete code involved. There was probably already another UITableViewDelegate in use on the tableview for the 'drilldown' behaviour. You could add this WillDisplay function to that UITableViewDelegate. But it is impossible to say because this code doens't display where your 'drilldown' behouviour comes from and if another delegate was already in use

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to do this.  All you need to do is to set the background color in the GetCell method, alternating the line color, as shown here.  It also solves the problem of not handling touches on a line in the tableview.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
        if (indexPath.Row % 2 == 0) {
                ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
        } else {
                ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkTextColor;
        }
}
```